# I can't find out how to fix my leaks in my own implementation of get_next_line function

Tags: c, memory-leaks, line

I'm actually writing a function called `get_`*`next_`*`line`  that reads a file, line by line using a file descriptor.
It's a school project, and it is teaching me what a `static variable` is.

I think I did well with the logic part of the function, I tested my code with a .txt file and many different cases like an empty file, 1 character file, 1 line file and everything is working fine.

But the problem is, I have leaks in my code and I can't figure out how to fix them.
Here is my `get_`*`next`*`_line` program, it has two files, one named `get_next_line_utils.c`, containing handmade libc functions like `ft_strdup`, `ft_substr`, `ft_strchr`, `ft_strjoin` and `ft_strlen` . And the main file `get_next_line.c` containing the main functions and some static functions for GNL :

gnl_utils.c :

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

size_t  ft_strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
        i++;
    return (i);
}

/*
    ft_strjoin that works exactly like libft's ft_strjoin.
    It concatenates s2 to s1 in a new string (str).
    It is used in GNL to concatenate the stash and the buffer.
*/

char    *ft_strjoin(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char    *str;
    size_t  size;
    int     i;
    int     j;

    size = ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2);
    str = malloc(size * sizeof(char) + 1);
    if (!str)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (s1[i])
        str[j++] = s1[i++];
    i = 0;
    while (s2[i])
        str[j++] = s2[i++];
    str[j] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

/*
    ft_strchr is used to find the \n and is used only
    as a parameter for ft_substr. (it's size_t len)
*/

char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        if ((unsigned char)*s == (unsigned char)c)
            return ((char *)s);
        s++;
    }
    if (c == 0)
        return ((char *)s);
    return (0);
}

/*
    ft_substr is used to get the line from the stash in GNL.
    In case 1 : Last line, it is doing a strdup of the stash.
    In case 2 : Not last line, it is strduping from start to \n.
*/

char    *ft_substr(const char *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)
{
    char    *str;
    int     i;
    int     y;

    if (start >= ft_strlen(s))
        start = ft_strlen(s);
    y = 0;
    while (start + y < start + len && s[start + y] != '\0')
        y++;
    i = 0;
    str = malloc((y) + 1);
    if (!str || start > ft_strlen(s))
        return (NULL);
    while (i < y)
    {
        str[i] = s[start];
        i++;
        start++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

/*
    ft_strdup is used to duplicate the buffer of read in stash
    in case of stash is NULL.
    stash become the content of the buffer and is \0 terminated.
*/

char    *ft_strdup(const char *s)
{
    char    *dup;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    dup = malloc(ft_strlen(s) + 1);
    if (!dup)
        return (NULL);
    while (s[i])
    {
        dup[i] = s[i];
        i++;
    }
    dup[i] = '\0';
    return (dup);
}
```

gnl.c :

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

/*
    check_line is juste a boolean that returns 1 if our string contains a \n.
    Else it returns -1.
*/

static int  check_line(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    if (!str)
        return (-1);
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == '\n')
            return (1);
        i++;
    }
    return (-1);
}

/*
    ft_strcut is used in one case in GNL.
    When the stash contains a \n, we are cutting the string
    from the \n to the end of the string, so our new stash does not
    longer contain the \n ans the past line.
*/

static char *ft_strcut(char *str)
{
    char    *cutted_str;
    int     i;
    int     j;
    
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\n')
        i++;
    cutted_str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ft_strlen(str) - i + 1));
    if (!cutted_str)
        return (NULL);
    i++;
    while (str[i])
        cutted_str[j++] = str[i++];
    cutted_str[j] = '\0';
    free(str);
    return (cutted_str);
}

char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *stash; //Static variable that contains the result of concatenation of buffer and stash.
    char        *buff;  //Variable that contains the result of read in a buffer.
    char        *line;  //Variable that contains the line to return.
    int     readed; //Variable that contains the result of read.

    if (fd < 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0) //Invalid inputs handling.
        return (NULL);

    //Init varaibles
    buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
    if (!buff)
        return (NULL);

    readed = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE);
    
    //If all the file readed OR error while reading AND stash is empty : return NULL.
    if (readed <= 0 && !stash)
        return (NULL);

    buff[readed] = '\0';
    if (!stash)
        stash = strdup(buff);
    else
        stash = ft_strjoin(stash, buff);
    free(buff);

    while (stash)
    {
        buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
        readed = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE);
        buff[readed] = '\0';
        stash = ft_strjoin(stash, buff);
        free(buff);

        //CASE 1 : Last line, no \n in stash. Read does not read BUFFER_SIZE but less.
        if (readed < BUFFER_SIZE && check_line(stash) == -1)
        {
            line = ft_strdup(stash);
            stash = NULL;
            free(stash);
            return (line);
        }
        //CASE 2 : Not the last line, \n in stash.
        else if (check_line(stash) != -1)
        {
            line = ft_substr(stash, 0, ft_strchr(stash, '\n') - stash + 1);
            stash = ft_strcut(stash);
            return (line);
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char    *line;

    int i = 0;
    int fd = open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        while (i < atoi(argv[1]))
        {
            line = get_next_line(fd);
            printf("Ligne %d : %s\n", i + 1, line);
            free(line);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

*Sorry for the indents, I have a norm to respect.*

I tried debugging for a week now and I cant figure out how to fix the leaks.
I deleted all my code and restarted many times, trying to get new logics to solve this function but no results.

Valgrind is telling me this (when I use ./a.out 5 in a file with 4 lines of text)

`➜  get_next_line git:(main) ✗ gwww -g -O0 -D BUFFER_SIZE=5 *.c && leaks ./a.out 5`
`==562032== Memcheck, a memory error detector`
`==562032== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.`
`==562032== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info`
`==562032== Command: ./a.out 5`
`==562032==` 
`Ligne 1 : toto`
`Ligne 2 : toto but 2`
`Ligne 3 :` 
`Ligne 4 : toto line 4`
`Ligne 5 : (null)`
`==562032==` 
`==562032== HEAP SUMMARY:`
`==562032==     in use at exit: 76 bytes in 9 blocks`
`==562032==   total heap usage: 25 allocs, 16 frees, 1,222 bytes allocated`
`==562032==` 
`==562032== 6 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 5`
`==562032==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
`==562032==    by 0x10935F: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:85)`
`==562032==    by 0x109581: main (get_next_line.c:139)`
`==562032==` 
`==562032== 6 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 5`
`==562032==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
`==562032==    by 0x490738E: strdup (strdup.c:42)`
`==562032==    by 0x1093D1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:97)`
`==562032==    by 0x109581: main (get_next_line.c:139)`
`==562032==` 
`==562032== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 5`
`==562032==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
`==562032==    by 0x10964E: ft_strjoin (get_next_line_utils.c:39)`
`==562032==    by 0x109455: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:107)`
`==562032==    by 0x109581: main (get_next_line.c:139)`
`==562032==` 
`==562032== 22 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 5`
`==562032==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
`==562032==    by 0x1092BC: ft_strcut (get_next_line.c:53)`
`==562032==    by 0x109518: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:122)`
`==562032==    by 0x109581: main (get_next_line.c:139)`
`==562032==` 
`==562032== 30 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 5`
`==562032==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
`==562032==    by 0x10964E: ft_strjoin (get_next_line_utils.c:39)`
`==562032==    by 0x1093F0: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:99)`
`==562032==    by 0x109581: main (get_next_line.c:139)`
`==562032==` 
`==562032== LEAK SUMMARY:`
`==562032==    definitely lost: 76 bytes in 9 blocks`
`==562032==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`
`==562032==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`
`==562032==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`
`==562032==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`
`==562032==` 
`==562032== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s`
`==562032== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)`

From what I understood, I have leaks from my stash but I can't free it because if I do so, GNL won't be able to write the lines remaining in the file. So the only free of stash in my program is when I return the last line.
I also understood that it's normal if I have `still reachable` leaks if I did not finish to read the file.
I'm pretty sure I free'd all my buffer that comes with the `read()` function.

But I don't understand that I still have leaks even when I returned the last line.

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: What do you expect this sequence to do:  `stash = NULL; free(stash);`  What do you suppose the `free` call is going to do?  You're passing it `NULL`.  It's not going to do anything.  Memory leak.

Comment: Always remember that the duty to free revolves around pointer *values* returned by an allocation function, not the variables in which those pointer values are stored.

Comment: nokosse,  BTW, better than usual implementation of `ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)`

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes.  (typo on my part) : nokosse, Aside: `str = malloc(size * sizeof(char) + 1);` is conceptually wrong. I think you wanted `sizeof(char) * (size + 1)`, which is even better as `sizeof str[0] * (size + 1)`. All makes no math difference when `str` points to a `char`.

Comment: @TomKarzes, I removed the free(stash) and I still have the same leaks and when I remove stash = NULL, It looks like my GNL  function is always returning me \0 instead of NULL.

Comment: @nokosse You need to first free the existing memory.  Then set the pointer to `NULL`.  Think about what you're doing.  You have a pointer to some memory that you wish to free.  How can you do that if you set it to `NULL` first?  You should be able to reason this out.  There's nothing complicated about it.

Comment: I fixed some leaks coming from buffer malloc right now but I still can't figure out where the leaks are.  Valgrind still saying that I have leaks in my functions strjoin, strcut and strdup.

Comment: @nokosse You need to make an effort to understand your own code.  None of this requires more knowledge of C than you already have.  What is required is the ability to look at your code and understand what it does.  For example, look at this:  `stash = ft_strjoin(stash, buff);`  This will allocate and return a new string, right?  So how do you expect to free the old value of `stash` at this point?  You've reassigned `stash` to the new pointer value.  Unless you have another copy of the pointer that will be freed later, you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: @TomKarzes, I added free((char *)s1); in my ft_strjoin and it looks like I dont have leaks anymore :) , Thank you very much. I was pretty sure I already tried to put a free in my ft_strjoin before and I was having invalid frees in my Valgrind. But I re-wrote my ft_strjoin this morning and maybe that's why it does not longer give me an invalid free.